# sqlite join query sample

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

I have 3 tables that name is productSaleStatus, productSalesVolume, productInfo

The productSaleStatus table structure is

`+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| productCode  | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sales        | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| year         | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| month        | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| day          | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| aFewWeeks    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dayOfTheWeek | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

The productSalesVolume table structure is

`+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| productCode      | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| optimumInventory | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| productDate      | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

The productInfo table structure is

`+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| productCode | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| productName | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

The example data of productSaleStatus is

`+-------------+-------+------+-------+------+-----------+--------------+
| productCode | sales | year | month | day  | aFewWeeks | dayOfTheWeek |
+-------------+-------+------+-------+------+-----------+--------------+
|           1 |   100 | 2016 |     9 |   30 |         2 |            1 |
|           2 |   200 | 2016 |    10 |   30 |         2 |            1 |
|           1 |   150 | 2017 |     1 |    1 |         2 |            1 |
|           2 |   125 | 2017 |     1 |    2 |         2 |            1 |
+-------------+-------+------+-------+------+-----------+--------------+`

The example data of productSalesVolume is

`+-------------+------------------+-------------+
| productCode | optimumInventory | productDate |
+-------------+------------------+-------------+
|           1 |              500 | 2016-10-10  |
|           2 |             1000 | 2016-10-08  |
|           1 |             1500 | 2016-10-20  |
|           2 |             2000 | 2017-01-01  |
+-------------+------------------+-------------+`

The example data of productInfo is

`+-------------+-------------+
| productCode | productName |
+-------------+-------------+
|           1 | test        |
|           2 | hello       |
+-------------+-------------+`

So what i want expect result is

`1, test, 150, 2017, 1, 1, 1500, 2016-10-20
2, hello, 125, 2017, 1, 2, 2000, 2017-01-01`

Can anyone write sample query to me?

Comment: Storing year, month, and day as separate columns in lieu of a single date column is usually a bad idea, and will make your query more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: i know , but the company already set that

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: but then SQLite doesn't have a proper `DATE` type

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes...but there are various levels of proper.  The months in this data are not all two digits wide.  I won't answer this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample data you provided, this should produce the results you say you want. Though I think you may need to add in a `group by` and sum `sales` with a full data set

```
SELECT pi.ProductName, pss.sales, pss.month, pss.day, psv.optimumInventory, psv.productDate
FROM productSaleStatus pss
      INNER JOIN productInfo pi
         ON pss.productCode = pi.productCode
      INNER JOIN productSalesVolume psv
         ON pss.productCode = psv.productCode
WHERE pss.year = '2017'
```